# Google Cloud Messaging VS Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

It says "Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is a free service", but to enable it I need to create a project in Google Cloud Platform which costs money.. 
So how is it free? or am I'm missing something?

Comment: Create a GCP project has no cost, actually, many GCP services have a free quota, for developing anything you want. It is most like "Pay when you go to production". But when you create a trial GCP account, you get 300$ of credit for use in services that doesn´t have a free quota.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating projects on the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) does not cost money. In fact, you can use cloud products like [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/), [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/), and [Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) (which all have free quota) without putting in any billing information.

For Cloud Messaging, it is similar to using APIs like Google Maps and YouTube: you create a project on the Developer Console, enable the appropriate API, and start using it with your key / configuration file.

If you want to use [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) VMs and products that don't have a free tier, then you need to use the free trial or put in billing information.

You should be able to use Cloud Messaging after the trial is over.

Answer (score 0):

you are not billed separately for using the messaging service however you will be billed for other features in the project.

Comment: Now I'm on the free trial. so I can continue using GCM even when it ends without upgrading the account?

Comment: I don't think so however I suggest to check with google.

Comment: If that is the case how does google make money from GCM.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit : It was like the carrot. To attract people to use it. This must have changed by now. My answer is almost a year old. I will not be surprised if they have started charging for it now.

Answer (score 0):

the first instance / server on GCP is free on daily quota basis. API is also free on a limit on  daily basis.